# ISO C++ forbids declaration Error

Tags: c++

I am getting a very strange compile error pointing to where I declare a pointer to my class.

```
MyClass* myClass; //Line 34
```

Error:

```
MyFile.h|34|error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MyClass’ with no type
MyFilee.h|34|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
```

I could not get a clue what is going wrong. Could anyone throw some light.

Comment: Did you `#include "myClass.h"` inside `myFile.h`?

Comment: Then we need more code. Show us what is above Line 34.

Comment: Are you using the same include guard in `myfile.h` that you did in another file included before it?

Comment: You are probably missing an include or the different headers use the same include guard. Temporary change it to `class MyClass* myClass`, recompile and see what other compiler errors you get.

Comment: have you put the ";" after the class body?

  class MyClass
  {
  ...
  } ;

Comment: Is this the first and only error message you get?

Comment: is there a circular inclusion ? i.e. you are doing `#include "myclass.h"` in "myfile.h" and `#include "myfile.h"` in "myclass.h"?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be declaration of `MyClass` is not visible at that point. Compiler considers `MyClass` as a new variable's name without type specified.

Comment: I have included MyClass.h in MyFile.h. What could be the reason for it to be invisible.

Comment: Have you included it above the declaration or below?

Comment: Does `MyClass` belongs to some namespace or it is in the global namespace?